# PHP - How to remove double quotes from data that coming from database?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have store data in database text field like this :

```
<p><strong>Relish Scrumptious Dessert Delights with Baskin Robbins Gift
 Voucher</strong></p><span>good</span><div>any rendom text</div> and so on..
```

So now when I print this data in front end then it should be remove HTML tag only show main content of field but no, it's show me same data that I store in database because it's taking it as a string means when I'm fetching data from database it's add **double quotes** at beginning and end of the data so it's read as a string and show me same data as I have in database.

I check using inspect element and show that it adds **double quotes** automatically so for testing I have removed **double quotes** using inspect element and all data is showing correctly.

I tried to replace **double quotes** with space using jquery when page load but my actual data don't contain any **double quotes** so jquery function is not replacing anything.

I tried hard to explain my problem I hope you guys will understand my problem and someone let me know the solution for this weird problem that I'm facing.

> UPDAT

BrandController.php

```
public function get_brand_api(){


$select = "SELECT
               b.*,
               GROUP_CONCAT(bp.p_name) AS price,
               GROUP_CONCAT(bp.p_skuId) AS sku,
               GROUP_CONCAT(bp.p_type) AS type,
               GROUP_CONCAT(bp.p_valueType) AS valuetype
               FROM
               brands AS b
               LEFT JOIN
               brand_price AS bp ON b.hash = bp.hash
               WHERE b.slug = :slug GROUP BY  b.brand_id
               ";
    $sth = $this->connection->prepare($select);
    $sth->bindParam(":slug", $slug);
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sth->execute();
    $status = $sth->fetchAll();

    return $status;


}
```

brand_detail.blade.php

```
<div id="container_detail">
  <brand-detail></brand-detail>
</div>
<template id="brand-detail-template">
   <div class="content">
      <h1> @{{d.brand_name}} </h1>
      <img :src="d.image" class="">     
   </div>
    @{{d.description}} // HERE I AM GETTING HTML TAGS WITH DATA.
</template>
```

brand_detail.js

```
Vue.component('brand-detail', {

template: '#brand-detail-template',

data: function(){

return {

    detail: []

}

},

created: function(){
//var slug = this.$route.params.slug;
var slug = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";

var api_url = url + 'gift_india/brand_detail/' + slug;
var that = this
axios.get(api_url)
    .then(function (response) {
        //console.log(response.data);
        that.detail = response.data;

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.data);
    });

    },

   filters: {
removehtml: function (value) {
    if (!value) return ''
    var myContent = value;
    return myContent.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
},
strtoarr: function (value) {

    var array = JSON.parse("[" + value + "]");
    return array;
}


}



});



 new Vue({



 el: '#container_detail'



 })
```

above blade template code is related Vue js so there is some rendom tags and template.

Comment: Do you mean, You can only display plain text right? like _"Relish Scrumptious Dessert Delights with Baskin Robbins Gift Voucher good any rendom text and so on.."_

Comment: Could you show the code where you are including this text/html in your web page?

Comment: @purvik7373 I think he meant the page displays the tags as raw string

Comment: @T.Adak you are right. page is showing me html tag also like <p> hello friend</p> but it should be show like hello friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [strip tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function in case you want to remove the tags

```
echo strip_tags($text);
```

If you want to replace the double quotes, and consider it as HTML use the below code.

```
$html = str_replace('"', '', $text);
```

Comment: I want it to done with jquery function can you show me that?  I'm working with laravel  , Vue js so I need to apply all functionality using Vue js and it's same as jquery.

Comment: Can you show us your controller code and your blade file code.

Comment: I don't thing you need any controller or blade template code because all data is come using Vue js. issue is that it's add double quotes at beginning and end but that quotes are not there in data. so I can't replace that quotes using jquery replace function because actual data don't have any double quotes.

Comment: I have update my question and add code for understating.

Answer (score 0):

Use str_replace to remove all double quotes from the string.

```
$data = str_replace('"', '', $text);
```

Comment: I need it to be done with jquery. not PHP sorry!!!!! and my actual data don't contain double quotes. it's added by system or anything I don't know.

Comment: @watson Seeing the code might help understand what's wrong..Could you pls show that?

Comment: @T.Adak I have update my question and add code for understating.